# Python 3.5 :Simulate dropdown for combobox

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I want the values of the combobox to get listed as soon as some text is typed in the combobox without clicking the arrow button.Is there any way i can simulate this arrow click ?

Comment: `combobox.event_generate('<Button-1>')` will show the list of values, but I don't know how to prevent the list from disappearing when the text entry gets he focus.

Comment: I tnink there was example on SO which was using standard `Entry` and `popup Menu` to simulate `dropdown` with "autocomplete" values.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22020864/1832058

Comment: @j_4321 i want to create something like `<datalist>` tag  of html5 actually.I'v got the list values updating for every keystroke.`combobox.event_generate('<Button-1>')`   works , but as you told the list should not disappear when text entry gets focus.